# Testing Remote Procedure Call framework

Tags: thrift, corba

What is/are the ways to test any RPC(Remote procedure call) framework like
Corba/Thrift. Do we already have any test strategies defined to test such framework?

Comment: If "we" means yourself, then we here on SO can't tell you that. Otherwise please explain who is this mysterious "we". Next, I'm not quite sure if this question fits the scope as outlined in the SO Help Center. Please don't take it personal, but SO has a very defined scope of which questions are welcome and which may belong to other SE sites.

Comment: Each CORBA vendor does this in their own way, TAO and TAOX11 for example ship a huge set of unit tests that run all automatically using a perl based test framework.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean 'we' in the sense of a CORBA ORB then JacORB's test regression framework supports client/server testing.
See https://github.com/JacORB/JacORB/